# Loading JSON file in HIVE table

Tags: json, hive, hive-serde

I have a JSON file like below, which I want to load in a HIVE table with parsed format, what are possible options I can go for.

If it is AVRO then I could have used directly AvroSerDe. But the source file in this case is JSON.

```
{  
   "subscriberId":"vfd1234-07e1-4054-9b64-83a5a20744db",
   "cartId":"1234edswe-6a9c-493c-bcd0-7fb71995beef",
   "cartStatus":"default",
   "salesChannel":"XYZ",
   "accountId":"12345",
   "channelNumber":"12",
   "timestamp":"Dec 12, 2013 8:30:00 AM",
   "promotions":[  
      {  
         "promotionId":"NEWID1234",
         "promotionContent":{  
            "has_termsandconditions":[  
               "TC_NFLMAXDEFAULT16R103578"
            ],
            "sequenceNumber":"305",
            "quantity":"1",
            "promotionLevel":"basic",
            "promotionDuration":"1",
            "endDate":"1283142400000",
            "description":"Regular Season One Payment",
            "active":"true",
            "disableInOfferPanel":"true",
            "displayInCart":"true",
            "type":"promotion",
            "frequencyOfCharge":"weekly",
            "promotionId":"NEWID1234",
            "promotionIndicator":"No",
            "shoppingCartTitle":"Regular Season One Payment",
            "discountedPrice":"0",
            "preselectedInOfferPanel":"false",
            "price":"9.99",
            "name":"Regular Season One Payment",
            "have":[  
               "CatNFLSundayMax"
            ],
            "ID":"NEWID1234",
            "startDate":"1451365600000",
            "displayInOfferPanel":"true"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I did tried to create a table using `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`, but it is not showing me the data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1
(
SUBSCRIBER_ID string,
CART_ID string,
CART_STAT_NAME string,
SLS_CHAN_NAME string,
ACCOUNT_ID string,
CHAN_NBR string,
TX_TMSTMP string,
PROMOTION ARRAY<STRING>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '<HDFS location where the json file is place in single line>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the `JsonSerDe` you are using . Bu here this `JsonSerDe` you can use for you.[Hive-JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

```
hive> add jar /User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
Added [/User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/User/User1/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
hive> use default;
OK
Time taken: 0.021 seconds
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS json_poc (
> alertHistoryId bigint, entityId bigint, deviceId string, alertTypeId int,  AlertStartDate string
> )
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
> LOCATION '/User/User1/sandeep_poc/hive_json';
OK
Time taken: 0.077 seconds
hive> select * from json_poc;
OK
123456  123     123     1       jan 04, 2017 2:46:48 PM
Time taken: 0.052 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**How to build jar.**
Maven should be installed on your PC then run command like this.

```
C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Hive-JSON-Serde-develop\Hive-JSON-Serde-develop>mvn -Phdp23 clean package.

-Phdp23 is hdp2.3 it should be replaced with your hadoop version.
```

Or if you want to use inbuilt `JsonSerde` [get_json_object](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object) [json_tuple](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple)
if you are looking for an example how to use see this blog  [Hive-JSON-Serde example](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) .

I will recommend validate your JSON file as well.[JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: The solution you have provided there you haven't considered the complex part after "promotions" tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the official document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe)

when you are using hive 0.12 and later, use `hive-hcatalog-core`,

> Note: For Hive releases prior to 0.12, Amazon provides a JSON SerDe available at s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/jsonserde.jar.

you should first add the jar `hive-hcatalog-core`,

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/;
```

you can either download it from [mvn repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive.hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core) or find it manually.

then the hive table should look like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1
(
SUBSCRIBER_ID string,
CART_ID string,
CART_STAT_NAME string,
SLS_CHAN_NAME string,
ACCOUNT_ID string,
CHAN_NBR string,
TX_TMSTMP string,
PROMOTION ARRAY<STRING>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '<HDFS location where the json file is place in single line>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to load JSON file data in hive table

1] Create table in hive

> hive> create table JsonTableExample(data string);

2] Load JSON file into a hive table

> hive> load data inpath '/home/cloudera/testjson.json' into table JsonTableExample;

3] If we apply normal **select * from JsonTableExample;** we will get all data. This is not an effective solution for that we have to follow step 4.

4] Select data using **get_json_object() function**

> hive> select get_json_object(data,'$.id') as id,
>   get_json_object(data,'$.name') as name from JsonTableExample;

Answer (score 0):

For many versions of Hive, perhaps the best way to enable JSON processing is using `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` as previously mentioned.  This is the out-of-the-box capability. However, for some versions of CDH6 and HDP3, there is a new feature where JSON is a first-class citizen.  This exists in Apache Hive 4.0 and higher.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ... STORED AS JSONFILE;
```

Please note that each JSON object must be on its own line (without line breaks).

```json
{"name"="john","age"=30}
{"name"="sue","age"=32}
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL