# schema issue while loading data in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

this is my json file

`{
"reviewerID": "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L", "asin": "000100039X", "reviewerName": "Adam", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "Spiritually and mentally inspiring! A book that allows you to question your morals and will help you discover who you really are!", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Wonderful!", "unixReviewTime": 1355616000, "reviewTime": "12 16, 2012"
}`

the code i am using to create table

`scala> hc.sql("create table books (reviewerID  string, asin string ,reviewerName string , helpful array<int>, reviewText string, overall int, summary string,unixReviewTime string,reviewTime string)row format delimited fields terminated by ','")`

`hc.sql("select * from books").show()`

[output from select *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5gkE.png)

here the data under the "helpful" column is moving in "reviewText" disturbing other columns as well so what can be the the correct schema for such json file also why it is showing [reviewerID": "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L] in place of only [A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L] in specified column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the clause ***row format delimited*** is - each field in the loaded file is separated by a delimiter and the meaning of - ***the fields terminated by ','*** is - the delimiter is ',' in the loaded file.

So, the table you created interprets the fields from the file in the following way - beginning of the line till it encounters a ',' as *first field* and from end of the first field till it encounters another ',' as second field and so on.

*1st Field --> {"reviewerID": "A10000012B7CGYKOMPQ4L"*

2nd Field --> "asin": "000100039X"

4th Field --> "helpful": [0

5th Field --> 0]

6th Field --> "reviewText": "Spiritually and mentally inspiring! A book that allows you to question your morals and will help you discover who you really are!"

In case if you want to create a hive table that interprets json input, you have to use JSON serde.

eg:

```
create table <table_name>(col1 data_type1, col2 data_type2, ....)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

you may go through the link below for a detailed example.

[loading-json-file-in-hive-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453646/loading-json-file-in-hive-table)